# Vue Press Github Pages .md files not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, github-pages, vuepress

### Bug report

Steps to reproduce

Hi, I'm experiencing an issue when deploying my Vue Press documentation as part of my priviate Github repo. I cannot provided a demo URL as this may or may not be linked with Vue Press or Github.

I've generated a Vue JS project using the `vue create` command, I've added the Vue p11n module on top as this is a plugin I'm making.

I've created my Vue Press documentation under the `docs/` folder, and locally everything works fine. I haven't touched the config files as everything here is working.

I have a few files:

- README.md
- installation.md
- requirements.md
- options.md

These are located under `docs/`, and then there's the `.vuepress` folder within the docs directory.

Docs URL: https://stsonline.github.io/vue-les-application/

My github repo is private, and has to be.

What is expected?

Documentation on Github pages should load as per the local copy, sidebar should function, and navigation links should work.

What is actually happening?

When I push my changes to the repo, my github pages url appears to only load the README.md file, whilst leaving everything else non functional, e.g: unable to access those pages.

My repo url example is: `https://stsonline.github.io/vue-les-application/`

When clicking the Get Started link, it should link to the installation page, but doesn't also the sidebar nav is missing.

However, running locally, everything is fine, including the lovely green theme.

What am I missing?

I have to keep a parent `docs/` folder, as this is the folder used for the Github pages, and I cannot use a parent `dist/` directory. That being said, Vue Press appears to build that inside the docs directory.

My `docs/.vuepress/config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  base: '/vue-les-application/',
  plugins: [
    require('./plugin.js')
  ],
  locales: {
    '/': {
      lang: 'en-US',
      title: 'VueLesApplication',
      description: 'VueLesApplication for Vue.js'
    }
  },
  themeConfig: {
    repo: '/vue-les-application',
    docsDir: 'docs',
    locales: {
      '/': {
        label: 'English',
        selectText: 'Languages',
        editLinkText: 'Edit this page on GitHub',
        nav: [{
          text: 'Release Notes',
          link: 'https://github.com//vue-les-application/releases'
        }],
        sidebar: [
          '/requirements.md',
          '/installation.md',
          '/options.md'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My `docs/.vuepress/plugin.j`s file:

```
const { version } = require('../../package.json')

module.exports = (/*options, ctx*/) => ({
  async enhanceAppFiles () {
    const code = `export default ({ Vue }) => {
  Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
      $version () {
        return '${version}'
      } 
    }
  })
}`
    return [{
      name: 'vuepress-plugin-vue-cli-plugin-p11n',
      content: code
    }]
  }
})
```

Other relevant information

- [x] My VuePress version is lower and euqal than `1.0.0-alpha.47`:

  - VuePress version: 1.0.0-alpha.48
  - OS: Mac OS
  - Node.js version: N/A
  - Browser version: Latest version of Chrome
  - Is this a global or local install? N/A
  - Which package manager did you use for the install? NPM
  - Does this issue occur when all plugins are disabled? Yes
- [ ] My VuePress version is higher than `1.0.0-alpha.47`, the following is the output of `npx vuepress info` in my VuePress project:

Answer (score 1):

That is because for gh-pages to work, you will have to serve it either from a `gh-pages` branch, or from a `dist/` folder. Since you are building into the `docs` folder, that will never be served by GitHub pages. Your only solution is to ensure that VuePress builds into the `dist` folder.

GitHub does not allow any intricate configuration on the name of the folder where you can serve pages from. An alternative is to use subtree, where you actually publish a subfolder to the `gh-pages` branch: https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490